# Tiling window managers written for wayland

Tags: linux, window-manager

Are there any tiling window managers for linux like `xmonad` or `i3wm` which are explicitly designed and written for Weston/Wayland?

Comment: https://github.com/michaelforney/velox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sway is a tiling window compositor for Wayland:

[Github Repo](https://github.com/SirCmpwn/sway/releases)

As far as I can tell it's in it's early stages and not necessarily all that stable.